# Can I loop this keyframes animation somehow with Sass?

Tags: loops, sass, css-animations

I have a client who wants this exact keyframes animation to be migrated from their old website, except we want it to infinitely loop. I know that I can create a brand new slideshow from a JS array, but I was wondering if a preprocessor like Sass would enable me to just loop this thing the way it is. I appreciate any input.

```
    @keyframes slidySlidesFadeInOut {
       0% {
        opacity:1;
      }
      8% {
        opacity:1;
      }
      25% {
        opacity:0;
      }
      92% {
        opacity:0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity:1;
      }
    }
    
    #slidySlides {
      position:relative;
      height:301px;
      width:318px;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
    
    #slidySlides img {
      position:absolute;          
      animation-name: slidySlidesFadeInOut;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-duration: 180s;
    }
    
    #slidySlides img:nth-of-type(1) {
      
      animation-delay: 150s;
    }
    #slidySlides img:nth-of-type(2) {
      
      animation-delay: 120s;
    }
    #slidySlides img:nth-of-type(3) {
      
      animation-delay: 90s;
    }
    #slidySlides img:nth-of-type(4) {
      
      animation-delay: 50s;
    }
    #slidySlides img:nth-of-type(5) {
    animation-delay: 15s;
    }
    #slidySlides img:nth-of-type(6) {
      animation-delay: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the animation to loop add this to style:

```css
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
```

Or replace the animation name with:

```css
  animation: slidySlidesFadeInOut 180s infinite;
```

And this does not require SASS, although it is completely valid in SASS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! On the second iteration it starts randomly fading out like something is out of sync. I'm trying various things but haven't come up with a solution yet. CSS is voodoo!

Comment: Happy to help! If you are still having trouble, I would recommend creating a minimal working example on codepan.io so that someone can help you debug it faster. If I am not mistaken from skimming your code, the problem is that the animation duration and animation delay are out of sync.